# Differences between opening a browser in Amazon Echo and Echo Show

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit, openurl

I am using the following Code to open the Webbrowser on Amazon Echo Show

```
    {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
      "type": "OpenURL",
      "source": "https://www.amazon.com/",
      "onFail": {
        "type": "SetValue",
        "componentId": "errorText",
        "property": "text",
        "value": "Unable to open Amazon.com (${event.source.value})"
      }
    },
            "shouldEndSession": true
        }
    }
```

But if i try the same on Echo, it would only open a page with a blank dark background.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "OpenURL requires APL 1.1 or later." according to the [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-standard-commands.html#open_url_command) - there might be other issues causing problems too, but the version strikes me as worth looking into.